# Codeigniter loading model

Tags: codeigniter-3

In a Codeigniter application I have the following code:

> $this->load->model('movie_model', 'movie_manager');

My assumption is we can only load single model using `$this->load->model()` . I like to know what the '`movie_manager`' stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you would like your model assigned to a different object name you can specify it via the second parameter of the loading method:

```
$this->load->model('model_name', 'foobar');

$this->foobar->method();
```

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load many models, you can do like this:

```
$this->load->model(array('movie_model', 'movie_manager'));
```

assuming that movie_model, and movie_manager are your model names here...

Answer (score -1):

the second parameters used, if ever you want to rename your object name.
for example:

```
$this->load->model('movie_model', 'movie_manager');
```

instead of calling your method like this:

```
$this->movie_model->method();
```

you can call it like this now:

```
$this->movie_manager->method();
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted answer on the question.

Comment: i dont know why it is duplicated, i just post and answer with explanation with it. well anyway thank you for the welcoming gift downvote. cheers